# Add filters on objects using multiple <selects>

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I have 2 select's and i'd like to filter elements based on the choices of these 2.

```
<div id="elements">
       <div class='anElement' id="1" height="30" color="Red">elem1</div>
       <div class='anElement' id="2" height="45" color="Blue">elem2</div>
       <div class='anElement' id="2" height="30" color="Blue">elem3</div>
       <div class='anElement' id="2" height="60" color="Blue">elem4</div>
</div>

<select id="select1">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="Blue">B</option>
        <option value="Red">R</option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="45">T</option>
        <option value="50">NST</option>
</select>
```

Now i call the jQuery filter function to filter elements (for example on the attribute color 'Red'):

```
 $('#select1').on('change',function(){
        if ($('#select1').val() == 'Red') {
            $('#elements .anElement').hide().filter('[color*="'Red' "]').show();
 }
 ...
```

This becomes really messy though with 2 selectors since I need to apply, reapply and remove these filters dynamically in a right way so I get what I want from the options selected.

I have tried creating variables to check if something was changed in in the other selector but this got out of hand really fast with a lot of  different variables and else if statements.

What's the best and most efficient way to do this? Kinda new to JS and jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

1. fix your html and change attributes to data-attributes
2. cache your selects and divs in variables
3. give a common class to your selects
4. bind the change to the class and filter:

```js
var select1 = $('#select1'),
  select2 = $('#select2'),
  elements = $('.anElement');

$('.filter').on('change', function() {
  // hide all divs
  elements.hide();

  // filter divs depending on elects
  elements.filter(function() {
    var element = $(this),
      select1Val = select1.val(),
      select2Val = select2.val();

    if (select1Val === 'all' && select2Val === 'all') {
      // return everything if both filters are all
      return true;
    } else if (select1Val === 'all') {
      // only filter on height
      return element.data('height') == select2.val();
    } else if (select2Val === 'all') {
      // only filter on color
      return element.data('color') == select1.val();
    } else {
      //filter on both
      return element.data('color') == select1.val() && element.data('height') == select2.val();
    }
  }).show();  // show the matching divs
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elements">
  <div class='anElement' id="1" data-height="30" data-color="Red">red 30</div>
  <div class='anElement' id="2" data-height="45" data-color="Blue">blue 45</div>
  <div class='anElement' id="2" data-height="30" data-color="Blue">blue 30</div>
  <div class='anElement' id="2" data-height="60" data-color="Blue">blue 60</div>
</div>

<select id="select1" class="filter">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="Blue">B</option>
  <option value="Red">R</option>
</select>
<select id="select2" class="filter">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="45">T</option>
  <option value="50">NST</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is what i've been looking for i believe! How come that you're using data attributes instead of normal ones? Just curious.

Comment: I just think they are easier to filter on and if they are non standard attributes, then they should be done as data - some browsers may interpret the height attribute as you actually wanting to set the height - it's a legacy attribute for the div tag (divs should be style using css, not attributes) - see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes

Comment: if i chose to use the normal attributes, can i use a .data call to add data attributes afterwards, like $('#elements .anElement').each(function() { $(this).data('event', {height : $(this).attr('height'), color : $(this).attr('color') })  }) and still make the code work?

Comment: added as answer

Comment: if you use normal attributes, just change data for attr.  for more information about adding and reading data attributes, please read the manual: https://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score -1):

You can use `val` of `select` to filter the divs based on color attribute

```
$('#select1').on('change', function () {
  $("div.anElement").hide();
  $("div.anElement[color=" + $(this).val() + "]").show();
});
```

Also your `html` is `invalid`.

You need to close `qoutes` around color attribute `value`. Also `id elements` is invalid it should be `id="elements"`

```
<div id="elements">
       <div class='anElement' id="1" height="30" color="Red"></div>
       <div class='anElement' id="2" height="45" color="Blue"> </div>
       <div class='anElement' id="Div1" height="30" color="Blue"> </div>
       <div class='anElement' id="Div2" height="60" color="Blue"> </div>
</div>

<select id="select1">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="Blue">B</option>
        <option value="Red">R</option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="45">T</option>
        <option value="50">NST</option>
</select>
```

Comment: sorry about the html errors, a bit too fast trying to write out the example

Comment: Downvoters please explain reason and for once test the code.

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the problem of how to filter for both selects, you have just shown how to filter on one dropdown so your filter will work independently of the other dropdown, which is not what the OP wants - see title *Add filters on objects using multiple <selects>*

Comment: But in question OP has just coded for one dropdown and second dropdown has no relation with `divs`

Comment: Read the question properly, if you don't understand it then ask for clarification